# Facebook Canvas App not loading

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

The following code was used to create a web app and get data from Facebook user using the Facebook php sdk.

```
require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');

        $facebook= new Facebook(array(
          'appId' => $this->config->item('app_id'),
              'secret' => $this->config->item('app_secret'),
              'allowSignedRequest' => false,
        ));

        $_REQUEST += $_GET;
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($user) {
          try {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100),first_name,last_name,username,email');


          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
          }
        } else {
           $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'publish_actions,email',
            ));

           redirect($login_url, 'refresh');
        }
```

This returned the data fine and worked great as a website. In my Facebook app Dashboard I created a website platform for this app.
And as  website it works great.

However I would like to use this as a Facebook canvas app.

I added a Facebook App platform in my dashboard.
When I tried to add a page tab with this app on my Facebook page, I selected the app from "My Apps" and clicked use now, but the page comes up blank.

What Am I doing wrong. I also tried loading this in Woobox as a page tab, and again  nothing showed up.

But when I go directly to the canvas url, it works fine.

What is happening here? Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you entered a secure canvas url in the platform settings. This can simply be the same canvas url with https:// rather than http://.

Comment: For the same url entered in the canvas url field in my dashboard

Comment: Yes. Try that, then try reloading the app in facebook